# What is the name of the shell feature `>(tee copyError.txt >&2)`?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to log stdout and stderr to logfiles, but only show the error messages on screen. I can do this with:

```
cp -rpv a/* b 1> copyLog.txt 2> >(tee copyError.txt >&2)
```

Which I found somewhere in the web.

I just want to know how this `>(tee copyError.txt >&2)` thing is called? I can't google for it, since Google ignores characters like angle brackets and the parentheses..

Comment: File redirection (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: @terdon I think the OP has stated that he wanted to log StdOut and StdErr to files, but also still show StdErr on the screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   Process Substitution
       Process substitution is supported  on  systems  that  support
       named  pipes  (FIFOs)  or  the  /dev/fd method of naming open
       files.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process
       list  is  run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or
       some file in /dev/fd.  The name of this file is passed as  an
       argument  to  the current command as the result of the expan‐
       sion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file  will
       provide  input  for  list.   If the <(list) form is used, the
       file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the  out‐
       put of list.
```

You can search manpages by pressing `/` and then typing your search string, which is a good way of finding information like this. It does of course require that you know in which manpage to search :)

You have to quote the `(` though, because it has a special meaning when searching. To find the relevant section in the bash manpage, type `/>\(`.

Comment: I do a lot of bash, so I did a man bash > bashman.txt and made it read only. Now, I can load bashman.txt into another window in my text editor (read only) and use all the editor's facilities for searching and copying and pasting.

Answer (score 8):

`>(tee copyError.txt >&2)` is actually a few different features:

- `>(...)` is called 'process substitution'. It creates a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) file in `/dev/fd` and writing to that file will provide input to the process in the parentheses.
- `>` : In general, this is called 'output redirection' and allows you to send standard output (`>` or `1>`) or standard error (`2>`) to a file or process.  `>&2` is output redirection but in this case, the output of `tee` is sent to standard error (that's what `&2` is, `&1` is standard output)
- Without `>`, parentheses (`()`) will start a subshell. Running commands in parentheses will spawn another shell which will only exist for as long as those commands are running. You can see how this works if you declare a variable in the subshell:

  ```
  $ foo='Tom';(foo='Dick'; echo "Sub: $foo"); echo "Orig: $foo"
  Sub: Dick
  Orig: Tom
  ```

  As you can see, the `$foo` that was defined in the subshell is separate from the one defined in the parent shell.

Comment: No `>(...)` is not a redirection. `>(...)` is expanded to a file name. If you want to _redirect_ output to that, you need `> >(...)` but `>(...)` is more generally used where redirections can't be used. The OP's command can be achieved with traditional pipes, there's not need for process substitution there.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Would be nice to see the solution you had in  mind

Comment: @chhh, `cmd 2>&1 > output | tee err >&2`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas thx!

Comment: The first half of this answer is wrong, or at least highly misleading; it's true that `>` can denote output-redirection and that `()` can denote a subshell, but `>(...)` is actually a single, unitary feature that does not consist of `>` and `()`.

Comment: @ruakh yes, I had written it badly, fixed now.